# double '=' in initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, variable-assignment

I came across this line when I was doing some laborations:

```
 int home_address = current_pos_ = hash(key, size_);
```

And I was wondering what it actually does? (not the hashfunction or anything, just the "int variable = variable = value;" thing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That expression is read as:

```
int home_address = (current_pos_ = hash(key,size_));
```

It assigns the result of `hash(key,size_)` into `current_pos_` and it then assigns the value of `current_pos_` into `home_address`.

Comment: More precisely, it assigns into `current_pos_`, but *initializes* `home_address`.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operator evaluates to the final value of its left argument, so this code assigns `hash(key, size_)` to `current_pos_`, and initialises `home_address` with the new value of `current_pos_`.

The assignment operator can be overloaded to return any value of any type, so in general, the behaviour of this expression is to call the assignment operator of `current_pos_` with the result of `hash(key, size_)` (perhaps performing implicit conversions), and then to initialise  `home_address` with the return value of the assignment operator (again perhaps performing implicit conversions).

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = y = 0;
```

Is the same as

```
int x = 0;
y = 0;
```

Comment: That's not exactly it. It's closer to `int y = 0; int x = y;`

Comment: Yes, it does assign the value to y before assigning it to x.

Comment: @Mat it is closer to `int y; y = 0; x = y; . Note the assignment to `y` as opposed to the initialization.

Comment: @juanchopanza Assuming `int y;` somewhere, it is more like this : `y=0; int x = y;` :)